# Python: How to ignore comments only at the beginning of the line of a file to get the clean Panda DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have.ASC data files in a directory being written into it by another program and the data look something like this
[image]

the data is in multiple files where comments start with '/', the header appears multiple times in the file but I want to keep only one header for all the data rows.

the ultimate goal is to load the whole data file as soon as it's written into the directory into a Pandas Dataframe. I have tried simple Pandas read_csv as only on the one file

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("demo.txt", header = None, sep = "\s+",comment='/')
df.head()
```

and got the following result:

[image]

later I tried to use the traditional python read file operation which works but partially as you can see that it's skipping many rows.

```
f = open("demo.txt", "r")
for i in f:
    if not (f.readline(1)=='/'):
        f2 = open("demofile2.txt", "a")
        f2.write(f.readline())
    
f2.close()
```

[image]

```
the algorithm could be:
read one file or multiple files or as soon as a new file written into the directory
read it directly as .ASC if not change to . TXT a
keep the headers in the first row and discard all the comments.
```

Note: i have manually changed the type .ASC to.TXT,

Update: trying to add a smaller dataset which can be locally copy-pasted

```
/comments start

/comments end
/id h1  h2  h3  Date        h5
0   1   41  0   12/4/2018   0
1   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
2   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
3   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
4   1   90  0   12/4/2018   0
/comments start

/comments end                   
/id h1  h2  h3  Date        h5
5   1   41  0   12/4/2018   0
6   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
7   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
8   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
9   1   90  0   12/4/2018   0
```

want it to look like this:

```
id  h1  h2  h3  Date        h5
0   1   41  0   12/4/2018   0
1   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
2   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
3   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
4   1   90  0   12/4/2018   0
5   1   41  0   12/4/2018   0
6   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
7   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
8   1   0   0   12/4/2018   0
9   1   90  0   12/4/2018   0
```

Notice that this pattern repeats in the file several times, i.e comments,->headers->data
comments->headers->data and so on. and there are multiple files in the directory.

Comment: Notice you have `/` in the date as well, this is why the `pandas.read_csv` doesn't work for you

Comment: yes that's why I tried the other method by first removing the '/' only in the beginning and later converting it to pandas data frame but problem is that this method is skipping many rows

Comment: Could you provide a copy paste example of your table (images are not useful for that)? Then we can try it out ourselves.

Comment: @Thymen actually tried to find a way to put the csv or .asc data but i could not find any way to load it in this question

Comment: @awaisumar could you provided the image example as a codeblock (if the answer below doesn't already solve your problem)?

Comment: @Thymen i have updated the question 
the problem has been solved partially, but I want an automated way to read all the.ASC files as soon as they are written in the directory, read the header only once following the data from all the files. you can make multiple copies of the .ASC file to check it locally for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your second method is on the right track, but I think there is an issue where calling `readline(1)` is reading one byte and when you make a subsequent call, you are not getting the full line. In addition, the file handle `f2` is being re-assigned to an open file multiple times; it really should be closed before being re-assigned, or better, it should be re-used for each call until you are done. It's possible that there is an issue where some of your writes are not getting flushed to disk.

Something like this should allow you to reformat your input CSV so that all of the lines with a leading `/` are removed.

```
with open("input.txt") as csv, open("output.txt", "w") as out:
    for line in csv:
        if not line.startswith("/"):
            out.write(line)
```

Comment: that solves part of the problem in a cleaner way, do you think this way would be suitable for larger files as well?

how can i keep the first header and skipping rest of them, actually all the header also starts with comment symbol

Comment: I don't know enough about your files to know how to be sure which line(s) contain the header. If you know the header column names, you could pass them to `read_csv` using the `names` kwarg (still keep your `header=None`): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution, might not be the cleanest solution:

```
import pandas as pd

headers = None
results = []
with open('input.asc', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        skip_comments = False
        if line.startswith('/comments start'):
            skip_comments = True
            continue

        if line.startswith("/comments end"):
            skip_comments = False
            continue

        if line.strip() and not skip_comments:
            if line.startswith("/"):
                headers = [word for word in line[1:].strip().split(' ') if word]
                headers = list(map(str.strip, headers))
            else:
                results.append([word for word in line.strip().split(' ') if word])

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=headers)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  id h1  h2 h3       Date h5
0  0  1  41  0  12/4/2018  0
1  1  1   0  0  12/4/2018  0
2  2  1   0  0  12/4/2018  0
3  3  1   0  0  12/4/2018  0
4  4  1  90  0  12/4/2018  0
5  5  1  41  0  12/4/2018  0
6  6  1   0  0  12/4/2018  0
7  7  1   0  0  12/4/2018  0
8  8  1   0  0  12/4/2018  0
9  9  1  90  0  12/4/2018  0
```

#### Explanation

Since the comments have a certain start and end sequence, I use them as a start and stop signal for skipping the lines that are in between.

Then I noticed the pattern of always starting with a `/` for lines that contain the headers, I use this as a filter for checking the headers, which I am manually parsing using:

```
headers = [word for word in line[1:].strip().split(' ') if word]
headers = list(map(str.strip, headers))
```

The first line collects whole words, this means that it won't work for when the column name contains spaces, for example `Date entered`. You will have to manually convert those cases.

Otherwise I assume it is a data column and also manually parse them using:

```
results.append([word for word in line.strip().split(' ') if word])
```

The disadvantage is the same as with the headers, and would break if the data is in anyway using a space.

#### Notes:

- I renamed the file `input.asc`, instead of the `.txt`, since it doesn't really matter.
- No items in the header or data can contain a `' '` (space) otherwise the parsing would be unsuccessful and you would end up with more columns than headers.

Comment: that's also a nice approach, I got similar results after removing the comments writing a new file as suggested in the above solution, and then reading the file using pandas data frame.
the disadvantage is that i had to make a new file for each file in the directory and also hard code the columns. so your solution is a nice approach too. thank you so much for your time